# How to automatically create list with 550 elements each, without the need to rename each one manually?

Tags: python, list, loops, salesforce, iteration

I would heavily need your help to simplify a code that allows me to have a data analysis on salesforce leads.

I have the following dataframes, which as you can see are split due to python limit on managing more than 550 objects in a single list.

```
Iterlist = list()
for x in range(0, int(len(List)/550)+1):
    m = List[550*x: 550*x+550]
    Iterlist.append(m)
Iterlist0= pd.DataFrame(Iterlist[0])
Iterlist1= pd.DataFrame(Iterlist[1])
Iterlist2= pd.DataFrame(Iterlist[2])
...and so on until the initial longer list is split
```

...
converted in the following lists for formatting reasons:

```
A= Iterlist0["Id"].tolist()
mylistA = "".join(str(x)+ "','" for x in A)
mylistA = mylistA[:-2]
mylistA0 = "('" + mylistA + ")"

B = Iterlist1["Id"].tolist()
mylistB = "".join(str(x)+ "','" for x in B)
mylistB = mylistB[:-2]
mylistB1 = "('" + mylistB + ")"

C = Iterlist2["Id"].tolist()
mylistC = "".join(str(x)+ "','" for x in C)
mylistC = mylistC[:-2]
mylistC2 = "('" + mylistC + ")"

and so on...
```

...

I want to create a loop that allows me to query from salesforce each of the lists using the following code template for example:

```
queryA='SELECT '+cols[1]+', '+cols[2]+', '+cols[3]+', '+cols[4]+', '+cols[5]+', '+cols[6]+', '+cols[7]+', '+cols[8]+' FROM LeadHistory WHERE LeadId IN '+mylistA0
```

and then finally:

```
sf = Salesforce(username='xxx', password='xxx', security_token='xxx')
```

leadhistory = sf.query_all(queryA)

I don´t want to write over and over numerous dataframes with specific names, lists and queries in order to get to the result. I would like to have a line for each of the codes written above, and let python automatically update the naming according to the number of 550 elements list.

I am new to this programming language and any tip would help me a lot. I think is possible to simplify it a lot but no idea how can be done.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the limit of 550 objects in list?

Comment: Apparently python   cannot process more than 550 elements per list in this query, hence i need to divide the aprox. 5000 leads IDs in several lists, each one big no more than 550 IDs. But by doing so i need to manually query each singular list. Do you have a feasable solution?

Comment: This is certainly not a python limit, a list can be millions of elements long

Comment: I know it, but in this specific query if I have 551 elements and not 550, i get an error.

Comment: SalesforceGeneralError: Error Code 413. Response content: Error: Request Entity Too Large: head

Comment: # The number of results might have exceeded the Salesforce batch limit
    389         # so check whether there are more results and retrieve them if so.